# Spacecrafts: NED frame to Orbit Frame or Body Frame Transformation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, attitude, attitude-determination-and-control

I calculate the geomagnetic field using IGRF model in Matlab. However, the output is in the NED coordinate frame and I want to tranform it into the Body frame.

I've searched everywhere and I cannot find any suitable Rotation Matrix to calculate the IGRF in Orbit or Body frame.

I have found a transformation matrix from NED to ECEF and ECI. So, if anyone knows how to go from ECEF/ECI to Orbital Frame, I would be on your debt :D

Comment: So does this boil down to ECI to LVLH (I'm not sure what you mean by Orbit Frame)?  If so, it's a duplicate of this: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33803/eci-to-lvlh-conversion

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not exactly. I have my satellite orbiting around earth with X to be the velocity vector, Z points to Nadir and Y follows the right hand rule. That is my orbit frame.

Basically, IGRF returns the Output in NED frame and I want to transfer it in the satellite's frame (body frame). I also have the R_BO (Rotational matrix from Orbit to Body frame), so if i can manage to find the magnetic field in the Orbit frame, I can transfer it in the body frame using the R_BO

Comment: Well, take a look at that question and see if the answer helps you anyway.  What you are describing sounds like LVLH to me.

Comment: @PoSeiDon I suggest to inject these into your question. A good question has all this 3: 1) what you want 2) what you tried 3) why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The direction cosine matrix relating the orbit frame and an inertial frame is as followed. Essentially it is a 3-1-3 body-two rotation sequence. I talk about the DCM a little more in detail here ([Calculate Argument of periapsis of orbit given focus and two points on ellipse](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37583/calculate-argument-of-periapsis-of-orbit-given-focus-and-two-points-on-ellipse/37833?noredirect=1#comment121174_37833)). You will need to know all your orbital parameters in order to calculate this DCM though.

[image: Orbit-inettial DCM]

NOTE: Theta is not true anomaly but true anomaly minus the argument of periapsis. Omega is the right angle to the ascending node and i is inclination.